# Decompression Stream in Delphi 7 and Delphi XE4

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-xe4

Following is my function which accepts a compressed file and converts it to a txt file by reading 1024 characters at a time.

```
procedure DecompressFile(const ACompressedFile, ADestinationFile : String);
var
  SourceStream : TFileStream;
  DestinationStream : TFileStream;
  DecompressionStream : TDecompressionStream;

  nRead : Integer;
  Buffer: array [0..1023] of Char;
begin
  SourceStream := TFileStream.Create(ACompressedFile, fmOpenRead);
  try
    DestinationStream := TFileStream.Create(ADestinationFile, fmCreate);
    try
      DecompressionStream := TDecompressionStream.Create(SourceStream);
      try
        repeat
          nRead := DecompressionStream.Read(Buffer, 1024);
          DestinationStream.Write(Buffer, nRead);
        until nRead = 0;
      finally
        DecompressionStream.Free;
      end;
    finally
      DestinationStream.Free;
    end;
  finally
    SourceStream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

My problem is that this produces correct txt file in case of Delphi 7 but in case of Delphi XE4, it introduces garbage values between each and every character.

Example:

```
Delphi 7: abcdedfgh
Delphi XE4: aNULbNULcNULdNULeNULfNULgNULhNUL
```

NUL is inserted in between every character. I tried changing declaration

```
Buffer: array [0..1023] of Char;
```

to `Buffer: array [0..1023] of AnsiChar;` but this did not work.

Comment: It is better to use array of Byte instead of Char for buffer, but it is not a problem here. For XE4 text looks like unicode encoded (UTF16?), for Latin symbols it is always pairs - 0 + ascii code. Are you sure you have same TXT file on input (maybe you create test file from code) and there is no any other transformations on output (like reading of data into String or something)?

Comment: It looks to me as though you have posted code direct from the huge application that you have ported. But if you had posted an SSCCE it would have been so much easier. Had you done so you'd surely have solved the problem yourself. Have you read Marco's paper yet?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - I am reading that side by side.

Comment: Delphi XE4 uses Unicode strings as default. Your output text files probably aren't garbage at all, you only have to open them as Utf-16 encoded text files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First let us assume that the decompression stream class, whatever it is, is implemented correctly. In which case, the code in the question is actually fine. It successfully decompresses the file. Although, it's a little sloppy because it allocates a buffer twice as large as you use. The buffer should be an array of byte rather than char. Use SizeOf(Buffer) rather than repeating that magic 1024 constant. And the Write call would better be WriteBuffer to add error checking.

The difference between the two outputs is simply that one is encoded with an 8 bit encoding, and the other is encoded with a 16 bit encoding, probably UTF-16.

Whether or not this is intentional is hard to say. One would need to look at the process that created the compressed file. For instance, perhaps the compressed file is created by compressing a Delphi string. In D7 that string is 8 bit encoded, but in DXE4 it is 16 bit encoded.

An obvious step is to compare the two input files, the D7 vs the DXE4 file. You expect them to be identical. But are they?

---

The other possible cause then is that your decompression stream class is broken. It looks like the ZLib class which is known to be good.

Comment: You are right. My XML file which was getting compressed was wrong. FCompressionStream.Write(strBuffer[1], Length(strBuffer)) accepts a line at a time and compresses it. But I observed the problem with Lenght(strBuffer) as it was halving the string because I think character size is twice in unicode delphi. So, I multiplied it by 2 to get rid of problem. My final delphi code is: FCompressionStream.Write(strBuffer[1], Length(strBuffer) * 2)

Comment: The code should be `FCompressionStream.Write(Pointer(strBuffer)^, Length(strBuffer) * SizeOf(Char))`

Answer (score 1):

This correction should solve the difference between D7 and DXE4 :

```
Buffer: array [0..1023] of **Ansi**Char;
```

But when manipulating memory, it's better to avoid chars that could create encodings adverse effects... it's better to use Byte

```
Buffer: array [0..1023] of **Byte**;
```

And then, without buffer, it's even better :

```
DestinationStream.CopyFrom(DecompressionStream , DecompressionStream.Size);
```